# Sequence of independent random variables, mean = 0

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Can someone give me a sequence of independent random variables (or an example of it, with explanation, if possible) with mean 0 such that:
$\frac{1}{n} \sum X_i \rightarrow - \infty $

Thank you.

Comment: I must be getting something wrong, but isn't it that the left hand side of the limit is the mean of those variables?

Comment: @Mario: He said the random variables were independent. Not iid. Otherwise SLLN gives 0.

Comment: For sake of completeness, you should include the type of convergence you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $P[X_n=n^3-n]=1/n^2$ and $P[X_n=-n]=1-1/n^2$ for every $n$, then $E[X_n]=0$ for every $n$ and the series $\sum\limits_nP[X_n\ne-n]$ converges hence by (the easy part of) Borel-Cantelli lemma, $X_n=-n$ for every $n$ large enough, almost surely, in particular $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i\sim-\frac12n^2$ almost surely, which is enough to conclude. The independence hypothesis is not needed.

Comment: Yeah, and in fact: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i\sim-\frac12n^2 \rightarrow - \infty $ almost surely (for n $\rightarrow \infty$)